# Замена src изображение, через консоль команду

Tags: javascript, html

Нужна помощь, после ввода скрипта в консоль он заменяет href, а хотелось бы src.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var _0xcae8x1 = document['querySelectorAll']('.item, .context2, .activeInfo');
    for (i = 0; i < _0xcae8x1['length']; i++) {
        _0xcae8x1[i]['href'] = 'vk.com';
        _0xcae8x1[i]['onclick'] = function(_0xcae8x2) {
            window['open']('vk.com', '_blank');
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос.

Comment: ну я бы хотел что бы при в вода в консоль он заменял не href а src

Comment: кто может помочь ?

Comment: да уже менял (((

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var _0xcae8x1 = document['querySelectorAll']('.item, .context2, .activeInfo');
    for (i = 0; i < _0xcae8x1['length']; i++) {
        _0xcae8x1[i].setAttribute('src','vk.com');
        _0xcae8x1[i]['onclick'] = function(_0xcae8x2) {
            window['open']('vk.com', '_blank');
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо но не помогло.

Comment: попробуйте вместо _0xcae8x1[i]['src'] = 'vk.com'; написать _0xcae8x1[i].setAttribute('src','vk.com');